What were the 3 charges of "attempting to influence a public servant" in the Tina Peters case for?
According to multiple press reports (e.g. BBC, CBS), among the 10 charges, on 7 of which Tina Peters was convicted, there were "three counts of attempting to influence a public servant".
Much/most of the press reporting alas doesn't explain how these specific charges came about, when Peters is also an official. Was she so charged/convicted on those 3 counts of trying to influence co-workers (using deceit) or maybe police/investigators? (There was also one count of conspiracy.)

The original indictment can be found here. and is relatively easy reading.  Basically, the indictment alleges that Ms. Peters (and her original co-defendant Belinda Knisley) deceitfully told various state employees to do things like create name badges & security credentials and run a background check on Gerald Wood, who Ms. Peters claimed was an outside contractor.
These were the credentials then used by Conan Hayes to copy the voting machine information from Mesa County's systems, and to attend the "secure build" of the machines in May 2021.
